# Gerhard Frey, "Links between stable elliptic curves and certain diophantine equations"

Tags: reference-request, paper-request

I am searching for the article by Gerhard Frey, which has indicated a connection between Fermat's Last Theorem and the Taniyama-Shimura Conjecture. The reference is give as

> Gerhard Frey, Links between stable elliptic curves and certain diophantine equations, *Annales Universitatis Saraviensis* **1**, 1-40 (1986).

Unfortunately, I am not able to find this publication. Is there an online-version of it available somewhere, or is contacting University Saarbruecken library the only option?

Comment: I have a xeroxed paper copy of it, taken from a copy of the journal issue obtained from the university library in Würzburg via "Fernleihe". You could try to do the same or ask directly in Saarbrücken. If you give me your address, I can also ask my secretary to send you another xerox copy of it.

Comment: @NicoDean: Did you manage to find a copy of the paper?

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. Yes, Michael Stoll was so nice to send me a copy.

Comment: @NicoDean: Would you be so kind as to share a copy of it with me? You can find my email in my profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please find here the scanned version of the manuscript [Links between stable elliptic curves and certain diophantine equations](https://github.com/FrancescaRossi/frey) by Gerhard Frey.